# How to publish azure pipeline test result to SonarCloud

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to publish my test coverage results into SonarCloud. My current pipeline is this [image]

Update: - In run code analysis step this log can be found. But in SonarCloud coverage result is not displayed.

```
INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report D:\a\1\.\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az185_2019-11-13_11_15_46\In\fv-az185\VssAdministrator_fv-az185 2019-11-13 11_15_34.coveragexml
INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: D:\a\1\.\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az185_2019-11-13_11_15_46\In\fv-az185\VssAdministrator_fv-az185 2019-11-13 11_15_34.coveragexml
INFO: Coverage Report Statistics: 21 files, 20 main files, 20 main files with coverage, 1 test files, 0 project excluded files, 0 other language files.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://medium.com/@chameeradulanga87/running-asp-net-nunit-tests-in-azure-devops-build-pipeline-and-publishing-results-to-sonar-cloud-20d14dccf275

Complete Guide to publishing test results

Answer (score 1):

> How to publish azure pipeline test result to SonarCloud

According to the document:

[From Team Foundation Server 2015 or Visual Studio Team Services](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Team+Foundation+Server+2015+or+Visual+Studio+Team+Services)

> 8. Optional: To import code coverage into SonarQube, add the Visual Studio Test build task after the build one and **tick Code Coverage
>      Enabled**

So, make sure you have checked **Code coverage enabled** in the VsTest task.

Besides, if you already checked that option, you can check if the version of your SonarQube is 6.5, there is an issue on that version:

[SonarQube 6.5 – Code Coverage Result is not displayed](https://samirbehara.com/2017/10/26/sonarqube-6-5-code-coverage-result-is-not-displayed/)

And, if you can get the Code Coverage in Azure devops but not in SonarCloud, check if [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/code-coverage-not-showing-in-sonar-cloud-but-does-in-vsts-build/1218) give any helps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ChameeraDulanga, Is there any info/message/error on the  SonarQube site? You can share a image about it. And Is there any error or warning in your build?

Comment: Nothing in SonarCloud. But in the code analysis step above mentioned info is there. Also after running the pipeline, I can download code coverage file and open it locally VS.

Comment: @ChameeraDulanga, I compared you and my log, my log is like this: `Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report d:\a\_temp\TestResults`, which the path is different `d:\a\_temp`, have you change the output of test result in the VS test task? You can share your definition for you VS Test task in your question.

Comment: Apparently I was trying to add test coverage to an existing project and Sonar Cloud only tracks code coverage in new lines. Thank you for your support.